# How do I suppress deprecation warnings for function parameters?

Tags: c++, clang, deprecation-warning

I previously used such pragmas, which I seem to recall worked both with GCC (ubuntu) and clang (macos). They seem to be effective to suppress warning from header `#include`s.

```
// test.cpp
struct [[deprecated]] Foo {};

#pragma clang push
#pragma clang ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

int main() {
  auto foo_fun = [](const Foo &f) {};
  foo_fun(Foo());
}
#pragma clang pop
```

However, it does not seem to work when the deprecated type occurs as a lambda or plain function parameter, when compiled with `clang -std=c++14 -o wat test.cpp`. The compiler version is `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)`

What do I do to suppress deprecation warning in these contexts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `diagnostic` keyword in your pragma declarations:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

...

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```